Trying to find an old book (fantasy or scifi?) in which the protagonist and their romantic partner live in opposite directions in time
I thought I was remembering Bearing an Hourglass by Piers Anthony, but I just reread it and that’s not in there. Now I wonder what book I am remembering.
What I recall is early in the book the character is being oriented to their new situation and a woman walks right up and kisses him - and he is shocked. She realizes he does not know her - and that means this is the first time he meets her - and the last time she meets him.
Their romance evolves through the novel as they live in opposite orders, both remembering the other’s future, and over time she knows him less, until the day when he has the same poignant moment: the first time she meets him, and the last time he meets her. Each time, the first kiss for one is the last kiss for the other. This twist was used again in Doctor Who (with River Song), and as soon as her character appeared I thought of this book… But now I can’t remember which book it was.

Nothing jumping out at me in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MerlinSickness

you are in the opposite direction of the book.

You might have gotten the right series, but wrong book. Not Bearing an Hourglass, but With a Tangled Skein. In it, Niobe and Chronos have that kind of relationship.
The first time Niobe meets Chronos in it, he kisses her, and she slaps him. From his perspective they'd been in a relationship for a long time. Later, Niobe seduces him for what is, for Chronos, their first time sleeping together and for her, their last.

Thank you! I pulled it off the shelf, that is next - too many years, i’m glad i was close!

Sounds like the lovers from Hyperion.  This story predates that, so I wonder if Simmons read this one.

@MarkRogers: It's been a while since I read Simmons, but the lovers I remember were not experiencing time in opposite directions.  He was a soldier traveling between systems.  Due to time dilation, every time he returned to her home world she had aged 20 years or so while he had hardly aged at all.  I remember another Simmons arc where a couple had a daughter who started aging backwards.  It was incredibly sad for me because it reminded me of my family member who regressed into dementia.

@MarkRogers: I just read Stef's answer below and he remembers Simmons the same as you.  I think the soldier story I remember might be from a Simmons short story.

@James: you're "merging" two subplots of Hyperion: the one you said (about a man who had to travel and everytime he came to the planet he found his beloved older) and the one similar to the OP, where a soldier, during his virtual training sessions, continued to meet a woman who was moving backward through time

I wonder if you might be remembering The Time Traveller's Wife:

Henry has a rare genetic disorder, which later comes to be known as Chrono-Impairment. This disorder causes Henry to involuntarily travel through time. When 20-year-old Clare meets 28-year-old Henry at the Newberry Library in 1991 at the beginning of the novel, he has never seen her before, although she has known him most of her life.

This was an inspiration for the Doctor Who character of River Song, which you also mentioned as similar to the story that you remember.

Thank you for the reference, i didn’t know that! I got to meet Alex Kingston earlier this year, and this story came up…i will have to look it up!

Thank you for that inspiration link. I would never have known the influence went in that direction without it.

That sounds a lot like "Z", a novelette by Charles L. Fontenay, first published in If, June 1956, available at the Internet Archive; you might have read it in one of these compilations.
The narrator meets "Summer Storm" for the first time, from his point of view:

Suddenly, there was a terrific clap of thunder and a fiery flash that blotted out everything around me. Shaken, I picked myself up from the floor of the bandstand, still not sure I hadn't been struck. Blue smoke was boiling away from a wrecked tree about thirty feet away, in the midst of a clump of charred, waving shrubbery.
And like Venus rising from the foam the naked woman stepped out of the shrubbery, followed by the naked man.
My first impulse was to laugh at these two whom the storm had chased from their hiding place and to be astonished at their brashness in disrobing completely in the heart of the park. Then it occurred to me that the lightning must have stripped them. They might be hurt.
I jumped from the bandstand and walked swiftly over to them. To my utter amazement, the young woman promptly threw her arms around my neck and said:
"Whatever has just happened, Don, I want you to know it's you I love."
Then she kissed me.
"What on earth!" I exclaimed, disengaging myself. The man was looking from one to the other of us, mutely.
"I'm Summer Storm and this is my husband, Wyn Storm, and we live at 138 March Street," she said, all in a rush. "Oh, Don, I'm sorry you don't know us any more, but I should have known from the way Wyn was acting and everything that's going to happen . . ."
"Wait a minute, wait a minute!" I interrupted. "I don't know you. How did you know my name?" She didn't answer, but just stood there, looking at me intently. I averted my eyes. I was beginning to recover from shock enough to be embarrassed.
"How about this?" I asked the man. "Why should I know you, and where do you come from?"
"I'm afraid I don't know," he replied, sounding perfectly honest about it. "I'm afraid I don't remember anything. Do you suppose I have amnesia?"

Conversing with a time-reversed woman:

A conversation with Summer was a unique experience. It was a little like two people trying to talk at once, each talking, then each hesitating to let the other have his say. Our words crossed each other, like scissor blades that do not quite meet. She might answer a question before it was asked, or take the conversation off on tangent after tangent. Disconnected, discontinuous—those adjectives describe our conversations.

If "Z" is indeed the story you remember, you left out the weirdest plot point. In a way Fontenay anticipated Robert A. Heinlein's 1959 short story "'All You Zombies . . .'":

"I was my mother. I am my own father and my own son!"

Summer is her own mother, but her paternity is not clear:

There it is. Wyn believes he sprang from nothingness, from himself. Amid the wreckage of the laws of cause and effect that this whole thing involves, it's possible, I suppose. But a couple of details still bother me, details I haven't mentioned to Wyn.
[. . . .]
The other is that year that I was Summer's lover. If she was living backward biologically, wouldn't that apply, too, to the growth of an unborn child while it was still part of her. And Wyn left Allertown right after Mark's birth.
I've heard of virgin mothers. I'd rather believe in a "virgin father" than human creation from nothingness.
I once had hair, and it was blond. My eyes are blue. I look in the mirror, and then I look at Wyn lounging at ease behind his newspaper.
My son? My motherless son?

The "explanation" for the sex change in "Z" is that a time-reversed man becomes a woman, in a far-fetched analogy with the idea that a positron can be viewed as a time-reversed electron. The title of the story represents something like a Feynman diagram.

That is bizarrely in the same vein! Thank you for the reference. I just recently saw Predestination, the Ethan Hawke movie based on All You Zombies, and from what you described I think you’d enjoy that treatment of it ;)

Dan Simmons' Hyperion Cantos, first published in 1989, features seven pilgrims on a quest to find the mysterious Shrike, a creature with time-altering abilities. Each of them has been chosen for their previous encounter with the Shrike, time-related troubles, and because they each have something in their life they'd like to fix, with not much to lose.
The second pilgrim to tell their tale is Colonel Fedmahn Kassad, a soldier who repeatedly met a woman called Moneta and fell in love with her. Moneta experiences time backwards so the first time he meets her was the last time she met him, and so on. They do a bit more than just kiss. In addition, she supplies him with weapons and technology and helps him take advantage of time weirdness. In the end he realises that they have both been manipulated by the Shrike to start a huge war.
Other pilgrim stories involve time-travel, poems, a daughter aging backwards (ie each day when she wakes up she's one day younger, and has lost two more days of memory), cyberdetectives, very-painful-immortality, and betrayals.
